# The trait `std::ops::Add<std::time::Duration>` is not implemented for `chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>`

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

```
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use std::time::Duration;

pub fn after(start: DateTime<Utc>) -> DateTime<Utc> {
    start + Duration::from_secs(1)
}
```

fails with:

```
error[E0277]: cannot add `std::time::Duration` to `chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>`
 --> src/lib.rs:7:11
  |
7 |     start + Duration::from_secs(1_000_000_000)
  |           ^ no implementation for `chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc> + std::time::Duration`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::ops::Add<std::time::Duration>` is not implemented for `chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>`
```

I couldn't find an implementation of `Add` to import. `use chrono::*` won't help.

I see that `datetime.rs` has an impl for `Add<chrono::oldtime::Duration>`, but `oldtime` is private so I don't know how to create an `oldtime::Duration`.

How do I get the `Add` impl I need? How do I convert `std::time::Duration` to `chrono::oldtime::Duration`? Is there something I can import to convert implicitly?

I'm using `rustc 1.25.0 (84203cac6 2018-03-25)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are functions to convert [from](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.2/chrono/struct.Duration.html#method.from_std) and [to](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.2/chrono/struct.Duration.html#method.to_std) `std::time::Duration` so you could just do:

```
start + ::chrono::Duration::from_std(Duration::from_secs(1)).expect("1s can't overflow")
```

But if you can just stick with `chrono`, just stick with `chrono`:

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc, Duration};
start + Duration::seconds(1)
```

Comment: You're right! I had somehow assumed there was no `chrono::Duration`.

Comment: Btw, if "Chrono currently uses the `time::Duration`" (@E_net4's answer), I don't understand how it ends up in the `chrono` namespace.   
I can even find Duration defined in sources for `std::time` and `chrono::oldtime` (the IDE takes me there). But I can't see it straight in `chrono`.    
There's something I'm missing about how rust modules work, I'm gonna make this mistake again.

Comment: @Vituel Crates can (and will often) re-export things with `pub use`. [Here](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L409) is how `Duration` ends up in the root of `chrono`. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

This is almost answered with a quote from the `chrono` [documentation](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.2/chrono/#duration):

> Chrono currently uses the `time::Duration` type from the time crate to represent the magnitude of a time span. Since this has the same name to the newer, standard type for duration, the reference will refer this type as `OldDuration`. [...]
>
> Chrono does not yet natively support the standard `Duration` type, but it will be supported in the future. Meanwhile you can convert between two types with `Duration::from_std` and `Duration::to_std` methods.

So, adding a duration to a Chrono date-time has to be done with this `OldDuration`, which is actually [exported from the root of the crate](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L409) with the name `Duration`:

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc, Duration as OldDuration};
```

Then, adding a duration can be done by either creating an `OldDuration` directly:

```
pub fn after(start: DateTime<Utc>) -> DateTime<Utc> {
    start + OldDuration::seconds(1)
}
```

Or by converting a standard duration.

```
pub fn after(start: DateTime<Utc>) -> DateTime<Utc> {
    start + OldDuration::from_std(Duration::from_secs(1)).unwrap()
}
```

This experience might be improved before `chrono` reaches 1.0.0.

Comment: Damn, you beat me by 10s with a much better answer :)

Comment: @mcarton I'm not usually the fastest gun in the west. But when I am, I still stick to my standards. ^_^ Better grab my cowboy hat.